# Missing POST data (occasionally)

Tags: php, html, forms, post, safari

Sometimes an HTML form is failing to submit any POST data.

There is nothing wrong with the form itself, the exact same form is submitted hundreds of times a day without any problems.

This error came about when a user complained about the functionality of my site. To try and work out the problem I added some email alerts which give me a copy of the `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_SESSION` and `$_SERVER` arrays. From this I found out that the `$_POST` data was empty.

My first thought was some weird browser issue but the database running behind the site shows that the very same user, running the very same browser successfully submitted the form within a couple of minutes of the error.

It might be coincidence but this always happens on Safari. It has happened a couple of times on Safari 5.1.9 and once on Mobile Safari 7.0.

Thanks for any help.

---

Some updates in response to some comments:

1. There is no validation used with the form (assuming you mean something like [jQuery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)).
2. I am not using any Ajax.
3. The following is the HTML form (with some formatting stuff removed) and a snippet of the PHP script. Although, like I said, I am pretty sure this isn't the problem because I have the same form used by the same user, browser and device without any problems (within minutes of the fault).

The HTML form (basically the user is given ten numbers and they have to input ten numbers):

```
    <input type="hidden" name="type" value="329"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="code" value="0"/>    

    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="2"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="5"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="8"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="1"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="3"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="9"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="6"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="10"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="4"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="start[]" value="7"/>

    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>
    <input type="number" name="input[]" maxlength=4 autocomplete="off" step="any" min="0"/>

    <input type="submit" value="Finish">
</form>
```

And the PHP file:

```
//First check the user is logged in
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
    //Check for the POST data
    if(!isset($_POST['type'])){
        //No post data - why?!
    }
    //Do stuff...
}
```

Hope this clears up a few things

Comment: Do you have any validation in the background? Once I had a similar problem with Safari and it worked as soon as I removed the validation.

Comment: Some code to look at might be helpful.

Comment: If you are using Ajax it may be you are not properly escaping a parameter value and its causing the post data from that point on to be lost.